# How to perform vuong test for cox regression model using R package

Tags: cox-regression

It is said vuong test can be used to compare two regression models that are not nested. But I wonder how to do it for cox regression models.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, from *technical* perspective, `vuong` function accepts regression model objects from classes `glm`, `negbin` or `zeroinfl`. As `coxph` is an object of different class, you probably *can´t* feed it to vuong function. You *can* feed the `coxph` to `plrtest` which is partial likelihood ratio test for non-nested `coxph` models:

```
require("survival")
pbc  <- subset(pbc, !is.na(trt))
mod1 <- coxph(Surv(time, status==2) ~ age, data=pbc, x=T)
mod2 <- coxph(Surv(time, status==2) ~ age + albumin + bili + edema + protime, data=pbc,  x=T)
mod3 <- coxph(Surv(time, status==2) ~ age + log(albumin) + log(bili) + edema + log(protime), data=pbc, x=T)
plrtest(mod3, mod2, nested=F) # non-nested models
plrtest(mod3, mod1, nested=T) # nested models
```

Now, from *theoretical* perspective vuong is a likelihood-ratio based test. And you probably want to make sure that it ok to use those for coxph from statistical point of view. Some [posts](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/310925/compare-non-nested-cox-models) claim that you can, some claim that you [shouldn´t](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/71485/how-to-interpret-and-compare-models-in-cox-regression).